# Erlang - If Else Condition

Tags: if-statement, erlang

Trying to compute a score and maintain it between a range 0.2 to 1.5 . 
Will the below code work ? I don't want it to return, but continue further.

```
     ok = if
       Score > 1.5 ->
         Score = 1.5;
       true ->
         ok
     end,
      ok =   if
             Score < 0.2 ->
                 Score = 0.2;
             true ->
                 ok
         end,
    put(score, Score),
```

Answer (score 9):

> Will the below code work ?

No.  In erlang, you can only assign to a variable once.  That is one of the first things you should have learned.  In this statement:

```
 if
       Score > 1.5 -> ...
```

the variable Score will already have been assigned a value, which you are comparing to the decimal 1.5. Suppose the value of Score is 2.0, so that the body of that particular if clause executes:

```
 Score = 1.5;
```

That is equivalent to writing:

```
 2.0 = 1.5;
```

which will result in a pattern match error:

> - exception error: no match of right hand side value 1.5.

In erlang, once you assign a value to a variable, thereafter any subsequent assignment to that variable will be treated as a pattern match, i.e. the value on the right of the equals sign will be pattern matched against the value on the left of the equals sign.

---

In erlang, you typically use multiple function clauses to pattern match different values:

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).

compute(Score) when Score > 1.5 ->
    1.5;
compute(Score) when Score < 0.2 ->
    0.2;
compute(Score) ->
    Score.
```

In the shell:

```
1> c(my).
my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,my}

2> Score1 = my:compute(1.6).
1.5

3> Score2 = my:compute(1.5).
1.5

4> Score3 = my:compute(1.2).
1.2

5> Score4 = my:compute(0.1).
0.2

6> Score5 = my:compute(0.2). 
0.2
```

Then you can define another function in the same module like this:

```
do_stuff(Score) ->
    NewScore = compute(Score),
    %Do something with NewScore here...
```

If you want to use an if-statement, I would do it like this:

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).

do_stuff(Score) ->
    NewScore = if 
                   Score > 1.5   -> 1.5;
                   Score < 0.2   -> 0.2;
                   true          -> Score
               end,
    %Do something with NewScore here, for instance:
    io:format("~w~n", [NewScore]).
```

In an effort to keep your functions no longer than 5-6 lines, it would help to move that if-statement into another function.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to use [`erlang:min/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#min-2) and [`erlang:max/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#max-2) to maintain the range:

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).

do_stuff(Score) ->
    max(min(Score, 1.5), 0.2).
```

If `Score` is greater than 1.5, `min/2` will return 1.5, else `Score`. Then, if that result is less than 0.2, `max/2` will return 0.2, else the result of `min/2`. Here's our test function:

```
test_do_stuff() ->
    ScoresAndResults = [{0, 0.2},
                        {1.5, 1.5},
                        {0.2, 0.2},
                        {1.4999999, 1.4999999},
                        {1.5000001, 1.5},
                        {42, 1.5},
                        {0.19999999, 0.2},
                        {0.2000000000001, 0.2000000000001},
                        {1.2, 1.2},
                        {1, 1},
                        {-1, 0.2}],
    {Scores, Results} = lists:unzip(ScoresAndResults),
    Results = [do_stuff(Score) || Score <- Scores].
```

Running it produces the expected results:

```
1> my:test_do_stuff().
[0.2,1.5,0.2,1.4999999,1.5,1.5,0.2,0.2000000000001,1.2,1,0.2]
```